# Ephemeral Amazon disc mounted in /tmp

Tags: mount, amazon-ebs, tmp

I would like to know what do you think about mounting the ephemeral disc in /tmp when using Ubuntu in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea. `/tmp` is not intended to be persistent across reboots, so having it disappear during such an event is built into the assumptions of `/tmp`. I'm doing just that right now, as we need a rather larger `/tmp` space than the EBS-backed root volume would economically permit.